# Why trailing slash changing the type of request in Lumen?

Tags: php, lumen, lumen-5.3

I am new to Lumen and I have defined routes like this:

```
$app->group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function ($app) {

    $app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
        return $app->version();
    });
    
    $app->get('users[/{userId}]', ['uses' => 'UserController@getUsers']);
    
    $app->post('users[/{userId}]', ['uses' => 'UserController@saveUsers']);
    
    $app->delete('users/{userId}[/]', ['uses' => 'UserController@deleteUsers']);
});
```

And my controller is like:

```
public function getUsers($userId = '') {

        try {
            return array('status' => 1, 'users' => ($userId != '') ? User::findOrFail($userId) : User::all());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return array('status' => 0, 'message' => 'error occured : ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public function saveUsers($userId = '') {
        
        try {
            $user = ($userId != '') ? User::find($userId) : new User;
            $user->save();
            return array('status' => 1, 'message' => 'user saved successfully', 'userId' => $user->userId);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return array('status' => 0, 'message' => 'failed to save user : ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

If am trying to hit the url with trailing slash, it's going to `getUsers` and if I remove the trailing slash it's going to `saveUsers`.

Note: I am using Lumen version 5.3.3 and trying POST request with REST Easy extension in Firefox.

Comment: You should provide the code that is making the request.

Comment: @isa424 i have already mentioned, am trying to hit the API through REST client.

Comment: Just to clarify: When you attempt a POST request with your Firefox REST extension, a trailing slash - ie: users/{userId}/ - takes you to the `getUsers` method, and no trailing slash - ie: users/{user_id} - takes you to the `saveUsers` method?

Comment: yes you got it right..!!

Comment: If you temporarily remove the authentication middleware group, what happens then?

Comment: @maiorano84 no difference.. same behavior..!!

Comment: That's weird. I had tested your routes in [PostMan](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) in Chrome, and everything appears normal. Can you verify if using a different Rest API Client works for you?